# Cannot understand mocks

Tags: spring-boot, rest, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write tests for my Spring Boot application that has some end points, it's a REST application.

I have the "usual" simple web application with a controller, a service and a repository. CRUD operations.

In my update endpoint I call the service layer to perform the update, like this:

```
@PutMapping
public Post updatePost(@RequestBody Post post) {
    return postService.updatePost(post);
}
```

The `updatePost` method on the `PostService` class makes some checks about the object before updating in it, and if the checks all pass, then the update operation is perforrmed, like this:

```
public Post updatePost(Post post) {
    if (post == null || post.getId() == null) {
        throw new PostGenericException();
    }
        
    Post postToUpdate = postRepo.findById(post.getId()).orElseThrow(PostGenericException::new);
    bool isOk = true;
    // some other checks..
    if (!isOk) {
        throw new PostGenericException();
    }
    // update operation
    postToUpdate.setMessage(post.getMessage());
    ....
    return postRepo.save(postToUpdate);
}
```

From what I've seen online in the test class I have to do something like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(PostController.class)
public class PostControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private PostService postService;

    @Test
    public void updatePost() throws Exception {
        Post post = new Post(...);

        Mockito.when(postService.updatePost(post)).thenReturn(post);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/posts")
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .content(this.mapper.writeValueAsString(post)))
          .andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$", notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

So here in the test method I'm completely replacing the logic of the `updatePost` method of the service layer with a fake one.

How is this useful?

The only good reason I can think of is that here I'm trying to test the endpoint by itself, meaning that I simply want to check if I can reach that endpoint, but I don't really care about the implementation at all, i.e how the update operation is performed. I'm expecting that if I make a `PUT` request to that endpoint I get a result, if the test fails I know that the controller doesn't handler that endpoint anymore.

Is this all about it or am I missing something?

If I remember correctly, Kent Beck also said that you don't want to test the implementation but only the public APIs, it doesn't make much sense to test the implementation anyway, you could have a lot of tests and at some point have more test code than production code.

Comment: I always have to look up the terminology used for the different types of tests and why. Heres an example https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/software-testing/types-of-software-testing

I guess how is it usefull? Really depends on what you want to test. Replacing a post request with a fixed result lets you test the code that happens out side of the request itself, i.e. you also dont need to actually request data from a server, can define the responses and ensure your wrapping code works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Using mocks may be against your testing philosophy, but looking at the practicalities:

Web layer is a nice chunk to be tested separately. There is a good amount of things that you can check:

- routing
- request and response deserialization
- validation
- error handling
- authentication

This also allows business logic tests to skip these concerns.

Additional benefits:

- they are easy to set up and run on a single machine (or even single process)
- they are reasonably fast